# C++ build error Netbeans using Qt and Cygwin

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans, cygwin

I have installed Cygwin compiler and I am attempting to run a C++ QT Application from within Netbeans.

As you can see from this screenshot, I have successfully set up the native build tools using Netbeans:

[image]

Unfortunately when attempting to run my program, I get the following error:

```
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/User/Documents/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:67: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/User/Documents/NetBeansProjects/QtApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Just to be clear, I am not running a complicated program, in fact, I am just trying to execute a basic generated main file:

```
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // initialize resources, if needed
    // Q_INIT_RESOURCE(resfile);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    // create and show your widgets here

    return app.exec();
}
```

I have been stuck on this problem for a while and would really appreciate your help.

You can download my Makefile-Debug and Makefile-impl [here](http://wikisend.com/download/348612/makefiles.zip).

Comment: 1. Are you able to build a simple hello world program?
2. Could you send us the makefile `Makefile-Debug.mk` which should be in someplace in the project directory?

Comment: Hello, I have provided the link above, will link here for your convenience: http://wikisend.com/download/348612/makefiles.zip - to answer your question, I cannot run simple hello world programs

Comment: I am sorry. But it seems not possible to work with Qt and Cygwin. Look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, according to the tutorial for configuring NetBeans for C/C++ for Windows, you cannot use Cygwin with Qt. You should configure MinGW to work with Qt.

[Tutorial for configuring NetBeans with C/C++ (Cygwin section)](https://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/cpp-setup-instructions.html#cygwin)

[Tutorial for Qt with NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/kb/72/cnd/qt-applications.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)